# Gmail's POP3 Account Import Limit is 5 - Any Way to Pull More than 5?

Tags: gmail, pop3

I've hit the limit with Gmail's POP3 account import.  I'm pulling email from 5 other accounts (non-Gmail) into a single Gmail inbox, but cannot add any more.  I do not want to forward email from more accounts into that inbox (for various reasons).

Is there any way around this?  I tried to pull Gmail account "B" into Gmail account "A" via POP3, but the system didn't like that.  If it had worked, I could have used that second account for 5 additional emails.

I guess I'm looking for a "POP3 account aggregator" that can somehow push/pull everything from more than 5 accounts into a single Gmail inbox.

Anyone else bump into this problem and find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

You should:

- create a new gmail account, let's call it gmail2;
- consolidate one of the existing email account in gmail2 (i.e. move it there, to have a free "consolidation" slot);
- consolidate this gmail2 account within the main one (gmail1), using the free slot you just created;
- add up to 4 more consolidated email accounts to gmail2, using the remaining 4 spare slots within gmail2. The one you freed up from gmail1 will be the first of the new set, that again might have a total of 5 max.

This way you get up to 9 consolidated accounts --four in your gmail1 plus the gmail2, then 5 coming inside gmail2-- inside your gmail1 or main account. You could repeat this using other gmail accounts, as far as I know, but have no idea when gmail might get nervous about it. You might receive emails slightly slower from the accounts consolidated from gmail2, in case that matters to you. It is a guess, but most likely consolidation happens with a certain delay, and you would be doubling it for the second tier.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks - I did think about "daisy chaining" email accounts that way.  However, I'm not sure that Gmail lets you "POP pull" from another Gmail account. I'll give it a try, though.

Comment: I wish this wasn't the answer, although it seems like it is. The problem with this is that you can't send mail as the emails you have delegated to 'gmail2'. :(

Comment: If you need to send emails from all of the accounts, yes, it might be a nuisance. But it shouldn't necessarily be too bad: 1) you could place your most frequent "sending" accounts into 'gmail1', and log onto 'gmail2' only when needed (from a pc switching is fast); 2) if you have Android you should be able to add 'gmail2' into the mobile phone, and use it to send from your less frequent accounts. I am not familiar with iOS to be able to suggest if you could do the same from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own mail aggregator using e.g. Azure functions, an example of retrieving e-mails over pop3 and storing them on a frequent basis in Azure Storage you can find here: http://lightswitchhelpwebsite.com/Blog/tabid/61/EntryId/4314/Retrieving-Pop3-Emails-Using-Azure-Functions.aspx
The additional work is then to read them from this "cache" and forward them to e.g. gmail.

Another option is to create an account at mailgun.com, add your domains, then add a catch-all route to your gmail account. Up to 10.000 e-mails fall into the free plan.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little old, but this is what I do:

1. I've got two domains that I wish to import mails from, example1.com and domain2.com.
2. On example1.com I have 5 email addresses set up, 1@example1.com, 2@example1.com, 3@example1.com, etc etc.
3. On domain2.com I have 5 email addresses set up, 1@domain2.com, 2@domain2.com, 3@domain2.com, etc etc.
4. I also have a 6th email address on each, mail@example1.com and mail@domain2.com.
5. In cPanel under mail filters, I set up a mail filter for each of the 5 email addresses on both domains to REDIRECT emails to mail@example1.com and mail@domain2.com respectively. I then add another filter to each, to purge the email after it has been redirected.

So now when an email is sent to 1/2/3/4/5@example1.com - it redirects the email to mail@example1.com. The same goes for @domain2.com.

In GMail I only import from mail@example1.com and mail@domain2.com. It maintains all the original headers, so even though it was sent to 1@example1.com and the filter redirected it to mail@example1.com - the headers still show "To 1@example1.com".

Now in GMail, although you can only import from 5 pop3 accounts, you can set up as many outgoing (non-alias) email address as you want. So you can set up 1/2/3/4/5@example1.com and 1/2/3/4/5@domain2.com as "Send mail as:" under Settings >> Account Import. That way, when an email comes to 1@example1.com - you can reply from 1@example1.com (directly via SMTP and not just as an alias).

Obviously this works for me because, although I have dozens of address, they're from two domains that I fully control. So if you're importing from domains that you don't control, or even if you do control them, and they are more than 5 - then you'll have a problem.

If you need more clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: Interesting!  I think I get what you're suggesting and I'll give it a shot.  Luckily, the "more than 5" email accounts I'd like to consolidate into a single Gmail inbox *are* on servers I have root access to.